How to get current user in save method of a django model?
I have the following django model:
class Listing(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('available', 'Available'),
        ('rented', 'Rented'),
        ('unavailable', 'Unavailable'),
        ('fake', 'Fake'),
    ]

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='available')
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ## 
        if self.status == 'fake' and  ......:
            raise PermissionDenied("Cannot save listing with 'fake' status for non-admin users.")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

I wonder how I can get the current authenticated user to see if that user is superuser, then they can set the status to fake, others cannot.
I
I try to see what is in args and kwargs. But they are empty.
Below is the view from where I am saving data to the model as a user.
@login_required
def create_listing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListingingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            listing = form.save(commit=False)
            listing.save() 
            return redirect('booking_list') 
    else:
        form = ListingForm()
    return render(request, 'listings/create_listing.html', {'form': form})


You don't. Django's models are request unaware. There are some tools that store the user in the middleware, but often not a good idea.

It's possible in theory, but this is bad practice.  Authentication should be handled by middleware and views, not by your models.

I came up with a new solution  user = kwargs.pop('user', None)  inside the save method of the model and pass it from the views with listing.save(user=request.user). how to pass it when an admin is logged in?

@MirzonabotMirzonabotov: please don't. Don't modfiy the signatures of the methods of models. All sorts of tooling (forms, admins, serializers, resources, etc.) all depend on the models, and therefore a different signature can break a lot of tooling Django aims to carry out.

@willeM_VanOnsem where do you recommend me to implement the validation?


I wonder how I can get the current authenticated user to see if that user is superuser then they can set the status to fake, others cannot.

You don't, or at least not in the model layer. Models are supposed to be request unaware. In fact, it is not even said that the models manipulate the database based on a HTTP request, management commands for example can also manipulate the database.
Checking authorization belongs to the view layer. So in the view, or in the model admin. A model focuses on storing, retrieving, manipulating, etc. the data in the database. The model thus essentially has nothing to do with what users can do and how they do that. A model only is supposed to make sure the database is in a consistent state.
In this case, we can for example make a form omitting fake if the user is not a superuser, like:
class ListingingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, is_superuser=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not is_superuser:
            status = self.fields['status']
            status.choices = [(k, v) for k, v in status.choices if k != 'fake']
and then pass the is_superuser in the view:
@login_required
def create_listing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListingingForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES, is_superuser=request.user.is_superuser
        )
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            listing.save()
            return redirect('booking_list')
    else:
        form = ListingForm(is_superuser=request.user.is_superuser)
    return render(request, 'listings/create_listing.html', {'form': form})

How to implement the validation that I have in mind? Link users with certain authority cannot pick certain value for a field

@MirzonabotMirzonabotov: can you share the view you are using to update/create the records of this model?

Justed added the view to the quetion description

It's up to you to implement it.
class Listing(models.Model):
 def save(self, is_staff=False, *args, **kwargs):
   if is_staff:
     # do something
   ...
   super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def create_listing(request):
  is_staff = reuqest.user.is_staff
  ...
  listing = form.save(commit=False)
  listing.save(is_staff=is_satff) 
  ...


What if we have and admin with less permissions?

what do you mean?

how to configure the input validations based on the permissions the users have?

check user permission before process.
